# Querying two tables from the database at once?

Tags: php, sql, join

I am trying to query two tables at once to show member's activity in a "newsfeed".

So, I have my two queries but I would like to combine them:

```
$status_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member_status_updates WHERE member_id = '1'"):
   and
$topic_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE author_id = '1'");
```

How can I combine these two queries so I can show them in order by the time they were inserted?  If a status was posted 5 seconds ago and a topic was posted yesterday, then the status update should be on top.  To do this, I figured I would need to combine the two queries.

But my other concern is if I sort them by the `ID DESC` would that mess up the display? For example: If a status update that was posted 1 second ago had an ID of 50 and a topic posted yesterday had an ID of 100, would the topic show up first because the ID is greater then the status update's ID even though the status update was posted 1 second ago?  If so, then I was wondering how I could sort them by the date, I have a timestamp for each record.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What columns should be returned and what column in each of the tables represents the time on which you want to filter for time inserted?

Comment: Does topics.author_id represent the same thing as memberstatus_status_updates.member_id?

Comment: The collumns that should be returned for 'status_content' for the updates, and 'title' for the topics.  Also - Yes, it will show the same user ID (@ the second comment).

Comment: Is it the case that should always get a row from the topics table or should always get a row from the members_status_updates table or could either be empty?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a Union All query:

```
Select 'member' As Source, <some timestamp col> As InsertedDate, ...
From member_status_updates
Where member_id = 1
Union All
Select 'topics', <some timestamp col>, ...
From topics
Where author_id = '1'
Order By InsertedDate Desc
```

The catch is that the column count and data type of the columns of the two queries must be identical. (Another reason to avoid Select *).

---

If you knew you would always get a row from the `topics` table and given that `topics.author_id` maps to `member_status_updates.member_id`, you could use a Left Join. If you also want the last row based on some timestamp value, you could do something like:

```
Select T.title, M.status_content
From topics As T
    Left Join member_status_updates As M
        On M.member_id = T.author_id
            And M.SomeTimestampCol =    (
                                        Select Max( M1.SomeTimestampCol )
                                        From member_status_updates As M1
                                        Where M1.member_id = 1
                                        )
Where T.author_id = 1
    And T.SomeTimestampCol =    (
                                Select Max( T1.SomeTimestampCol )
                                From topics As T1
                                Where T1.author_id = 1
                                )
```

Comment: As written this solution does not take into account @Dan's order requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I got the query to run. But I'm confused on how to actually display the results.  I'm using while(), but it doesn't seem to display to any information from the database.  The full array when I run the query is this: Array ( [0] => status_member_id [Source] => status_member_id [1] => status_date [InsertedDate] => status_date )

Comment: @Dan - When you run your query directly against the db (instead of through your interface), what results do you get? What about if you run one of the Select statements and not the other? The Union All is literally stacking two query results on top of each other so if you got no results, then both individual queries returned no results.

Comment: @Thomas, sorry I should have specified.  It is actually returning 590 entries.  I have text insider the while() loop which is showed 590 times, but the data from the database isn't showed.

Comment: @Dan - I've added another variant. However, is it the case that you should always get a row from topics or always get a row from member_status_updates? That will affect the nature of the join.

Comment: @Thomas I got it :) You've been a life saver and a great help.  Is there any way I can get in contact with you because I'd like to show my appreciation.  Please email me at: nerve [at] se7ensins [dot] com